# T-SQL, how to parse this XML?

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I've spent hours trying to parse this XML (bus stop schedule) and produce a recordset with ,  . Is there a way to convert XML to JSON, which I find is easier to handle?

Anyone willing to help? (Azure SQL Server)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Trias xmlns="http://www.vdv.de/trias" version="1.1">
    <ServiceDelivery>
        <ResponseTimestamp xmlns="http://www.siri.org.uk/siri">2021-11-25T17:52:12Z</ResponseTimestamp>
        <DeliveryPayload>
            <StopEventResponse>
                <StopEventResult>
                    <StopEvent>
                        <ThisCall>
                            <CallAtStop>
                                <ServiceDeparture>
                                    <TimetabledTime>2021-11-25T17:53:00Z</TimetabledTime>
                                    <EstimatedTime>2021-11-25T17:53:00Z</EstimatedTime>
                                </ServiceDeparture>
                            </CallAtStop>
                        </ThisCall>
                        <Service>
                            <PublishedLineName>
                                <Text>58</Text>
                                <Language>de</Language>
                            </PublishedLineName>
                        </Service>
                    </StopEvent>
                </StopEventResult>
                <StopEventResult>
                    <StopEvent>
                        <ThisCall>
                            <CallAtStop>
                                <ServiceDeparture>
                                    <TimetabledTime>2021-11-25T17:58:00Z</TimetabledTime>
                                    <EstimatedTime>2021-11-25T17:58:00Z</EstimatedTime>
                                </ServiceDeparture>
                            </CallAtStop>
                        </ThisCall>
                        <Service>
                            <PublishedLineName>
                                <Text>60</Text>
                                <Language>de</Language>
                            </PublishedLineName>
                        </Service>
                    </StopEvent>
                </StopEventResult>
            </StopEventResponse>
        </DeliveryPayload>
    </ServiceDelivery>
</Trias>
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: It would help to know what you are trying to do with the XML, and to know how you are trying to process it and what went wrong. Doing the processing indirectly in two steps (via JSON) rather than one seems to achieve nothing other than meaning you have to master more tools and libraries and there are more possible ways to go wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A minimal reproducible example was not provided.

So shooting from the hip.

There is no need for any XML parsing. SQL Server comes with the built-in XQuery language support to handle XML data type.

The only nuance is that the input XML has namespaces.

- A default namespace is declared by using `XMLNAMESPACES()` clause.
- A couple of XQuery methods are in use: `.nodes()` and `.value()`

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @xml XML =
N'<Trias xmlns="http://www.vdv.de/trias" version="1.1">
    <ServiceDelivery>
        <ResponseTimestamp xmlns="http://www.siri.org.uk/siri">2021-11-25T17:52:12Z</ResponseTimestamp>
        <DeliveryPayload>
            <StopEventResponse>
                <StopEventResult>
                    <StopEvent>
                        <ThisCall>
                            <CallAtStop>
                                <ServiceDeparture>
                                    <TimetabledTime>2021-11-25T17:53:00Z</TimetabledTime>
                                    <EstimatedTime>2021-11-25T17:53:00Z</EstimatedTime>
                                </ServiceDeparture>
                            </CallAtStop>
                        </ThisCall>
                        <Service>
                            <PublishedLineName>
                                <Text>58</Text>
                                <Language>de</Language>
                            </PublishedLineName>
                        </Service>
                    </StopEvent>
                </StopEventResult>
                <StopEventResult>
                    <StopEvent>
                        <ThisCall>
                            <CallAtStop>
                                <ServiceDeparture>
                                    <TimetabledTime>2021-11-25T17:58:00Z</TimetabledTime>
                                    <EstimatedTime>2021-11-25T17:58:00Z</EstimatedTime>
                                </ServiceDeparture>
                            </CallAtStop>
                        </ThisCall>
                        <Service>
                            <PublishedLineName>
                                <Text>60</Text>
                                <Language>de</Language>
                            </PublishedLineName>
                        </Service>
                    </StopEvent>
                </StopEventResult>
            </StopEventResponse>
        </DeliveryPayload>
    </ServiceDelivery>
</Trias>';

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.vdv.de/trias')
SELECT c.value('(ThisCall/CallAtStop/ServiceDeparture/TimetabledTime/text())[1]', 'DATETIMEOFFSET(0)') AS TimetabledTime
    , c.value('(ThisCall/CallAtStop/ServiceDeparture/EstimatedTime/text())[1]', 'DATETIMEOFFSET(0)') AS EstimatedTime
    , c.value('(Service/PublishedLineName/Text/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS [Text]
    , c.value('(Service/PublishedLineName/Language/text())[1]', 'CHAR(2)') AS [Language]
FROM @xml.nodes('/Trias/ServiceDelivery/DeliveryPayload/StopEventResponse/StopEventResult/StopEvent') AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+----------------------------+----------------------------+------+----------+
|       TimetabledTime       |       EstimatedTime        | Text | Language |
+----------------------------+----------------------------+------+----------+
| 2021-11-25 17:53:00 +00:00 | 2021-11-25 17:53:00 +00:00 |   58 | de       |
| 2021-11-25 17:58:00 +00:00 | 2021-11-25 17:58:00 +00:00 |   60 | de       |
+----------------------------+----------------------------+------+----------+
```